# declaration a @protocol in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, protocols

What means a word "USING" in declaration of `@protocol`?

The declaration is:

```
@protocol  name

USING

// declaration of methods

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `using` keyword in Objective-C.

Two possibilities:

- It's somewhere defined as a macro, in that case you have to look it up in your code. (Xcode helps you with this if you click on it using a right-click.)
- The file is actually Objective-C++. The [`using` keyword](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/using) comes from C++, but I don't think there's a special functionality in the context of `@protocol`.

Given the fact that it's written in capitals, I'd say it's a macro.